# Does this write or read an array?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, nscoder

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
```

I'm trying to figure out how to save and load an array using NSUser Defaults. I already have the NSCoding delegate methods defined, just need to know the actual commands to execute that will call those methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code stores the array:

- [`-setObject:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDHAGB)/[`-setBool:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-setBool_forKey_)/... store a value
- [`-objectForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDJDJG)/[`-boolForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDBBGC)/... retrieve a value

In your case you'll want to store it using `-setObject:forKey:` and retrieve it using `-arrayForKey:`.